# Не запускается скрипт для вывода правильной последовательности скобок

Tags: javascript, python

Есть код на для вывода правильной последовательности n элементов, переписал его под python, но он не работает. В чём моя ошибка?

JS:

```
    function getCombinations(space) { 

    const result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < space; ++i) {
        const leftSpace = i;
        const rightSpace = space - i - 1;
        const leftCombinations = leftSpace > 0 ? getCombinations(leftSpace) : [''];
        const rightCombinations = rightSpace > 0 ? getCombinations(rightSpace) : [''];

        for (const left of leftCombinations) {
            for (const right of rightCombinations) {
                result.push(`(${left})${right}`);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;

}

console.log(getCombinations(2));
```

Вот код на Python, который не работает:

```
def get_combinations(space):
  result = []
  for i in range(space):
    left_space = i
    right_space = space - i - 1
    left_combinations = get_combinations(left_space) if left_space > 0 else ['']
    right_combinations = get_combinations(right_space) if right_space > 0 else ['']

  for left in left_combinations:
    for right in right_combinations:
      result.append(f'({left}{right})')

  get_combinations(2)
```

Результат для 2 должен быть такой:

```
[ '()()', '(())' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написано же: "Ожидается отступ."

```
def get_combinations(space):
    result = []
    ...
```

---

Зачем Вы на ходу меняете содержание вопроса так, что ответ становится бессмысленным?

---

Ладно. Теперь не мешало бы вернуть из Вашей функции значение.

```
def get_combinations(space):
    ...
    return result
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)
Вопрос изменил зная, что его правки останутся

Comment: @Thornberry Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.